# blazor set object component parameter with string properties

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I was trying to do something like this:

```
<MyComp Opt="new(){ Prop1 = "hi"}" />
```

and this doesn't compile, I get lots of errors from the `source generator/ razor.g.cs files`

Seems that the problem is that I'm using `"` symbol inside a parameter value which is already inside `"` symbols.

Is there a way to escape this so I could define this object inline ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parentheses inside an `@`.

```
<MyComp Opt="@(new(){ Prop1 = "hi"})" />
```

or another example:

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => OnClickSayMessage("Hello"))">Say Hello</button>
```